# Box2D. Trying to understand how much force is needed

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to understand the amount of force i need to move my object. This is how my world is setup and the physics step is done

```
private void setupWorld() {
    mWorld = new World(new Vector2(0f, -9.8f), true);

    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(x, y);

    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    PolygonShape box=new PolygonShape();
    box.setAsBox(1,1);

    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = box;
    fixtureDef.density = 1f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.0f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.0f;

    Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    box.dispose();
}

private void doPhysicsStep(float deltaTime) {
    float frameTime = Math.min(deltaTime, 0.25f);
    accumulator += frameTime;
    while (accumulator >= TIME_STEP) {
        body.applyForceToCenter(new Vector2(0, 10f), true);
        world.step(TIME_STEP, VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, POSITION_ITERATIONS);
        accumulator -= (TIME_STEP);
    }
}
```

So i've got a 1x1 box with a density 1. Gravity is set at -9.8 and i'm expecting that when I apply an amount of force to my box that is greater than the gravity (in this example i've set it to 10) that the box should start moving up.

But the box doesn't move. I have to set the force to about 80 (i.e. `body.applyForceToCenter(new Vector2(0, 80f), true);`) before it starts to move the box.

I've considered that this is due to my time step (which i've currently set to 1/60f), but if anything taking that into account would reduce the force I'm applying in each step.

Can someone explain what i'm miscalculating here?

Comment: Are you sure that it does not move at all? Maybe, it is just moving very slowly. A force of 10 means that there is 0.2 left for acceleration. That means that the velocity is increased by 0.2 units per second each second. Depending on your scale, this might be very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your box has a mass of 4, not 1, because in method `setAsBox(float hx, float hy)` `hx` means half of desired width, and `hy` means half of desired height. So if you want to have a box 1 x 1 you will call `setAsBox(0.5F, 0.5F)`.

But this doesn't explain why you need a force of 80 to move it, because force of 50 should be enough to make a difference.

`Fg = m * g = 9.8 * 4 = 39.2`

On my test project on object of mass 4 even the force of 40 is noticeable when applied programmatically (the delay of application start and pressing the button is significant so I avoid it).

Comment: Oh I missed the setAsBox was half with/height. After correcting that and a bit more testing I noticed that I needed exactly 2x force I was expecting, and realized it was because I accidentally calling the world.step() already elsewhere...